# Reference 'this' in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, this, master-pages

I'm working on a new asp.NET project (.NET version 4.5 to be specific). I'm trying to create this project using best practices, but unfortunately I don't know the terminology to look up in this case - hopefully, this question will make it clear.

After creating a new project from the default template, I get the pages necessary for a login system. I now want to make it so that the entire site requires logging in before you're allowed to see any content. To do that, I simply check if your user is logged in on page load, and if not, redirect you to the login page.

Here's what I have so far - it works fine, but isn't "global".

On the individual page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If the user isn't logged in, make them log in
    redirectIfNotLoggedIn(this);
}

public static void redirectIfNotLoggedIn(_Default _Default)
{
    if (!_Default.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { _Default.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx"); }
}
```

It works - if I am not logged in, it brings me to the Login.aspx page. If I am logged in, I am able to navigate the site. The issue with this code is that I would have to copy and paste it into every page. I therefore would like to place this code in the Page_Load of the Site.Master file, which would force the user to authenticate no matter what page they're trying to access. However, I can't use the 'this' context within Site.Master, which makes sense - but I don't know what the alternative is.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way? How can I make the authentication requirement "global" for every page in the project?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and in particular the Authorization filters.

Comment: Why can't you use `this` in the master file?

Comment: @Chris I'm reading through the pages now, what exactly should I be looking for? Where would I put such a filter?

Comment: @Chris You have linked an article for MVC while this is using webforms so is not useful.

Comment: @DavidG although I guess I can use it, it is of type `SiteMaster` as opposed to type `_Default` - and `SiteMaster` does not have a definition for .User

Comment: @DavidG: Good point. Apologies, Jake. For MVC that might have been helpful but not for a webforms website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MasterPage, you can use `this.Page` to get the page object you are looking for.

But consider also a different way of do it:
I usually create a class `MyBasePage`, inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and put there all (or most) of the common logic shared by all pages in my web application.

Then I create each page modifying the base class from `System.Web.UI.Page` to `MyBasePage`

Comment: I believe this works - although I do seem to have found a slight flaw in my plan, in that it now redirects you to /Account/Login no matter what - even if that's the page you're trying to go to - resulting in continual redirects...I'll fix that! Regarding the rest of your comment, what are the reasons for doing it this way as opposed to my way?

Comment: Using a MyPageBase allow you to create a common behaviour for all your pages. Eventually, you can write that class with some virtual Method/properties and override them in only one specific page if you want to change the default behaviour. You can do it something similar also using MasterPage, but I find it easier working with it at Page level, and not at MasterPage one. Possibly a matter of taste, but I find it more flexible using the inheritance method instead of MasterPage one.

Comment: Let's say you want a member variable `CurrentUser` in all of your pages: is it easier to store it in `MyPageBase` or in MasterPage, having to reference it in every page as `(MyMasterPage) this.MasterPage.CurrentUser`?

Comment: Very true! Thank you!